# Power coefficient Cp of wind turbines

Tags: power, converter, mppt, windturbine

The power coefficient of wind turbine (ratio between useful mechanical power and the total wind power) varies when the tip-speed ratio varies. I know also that we tend to keep constant the power coefficient in tip-speed values of 8-10 (on average, considering a 3 blades turbine) wherein we reach the maximum power and later we tend to decrease Cp when the wind power becomes too high in order to keep constant the power (pitch control for example). My question is: how we keep constant the power coefficient Cp for tip-speed ratio of 8-10? Is this done with converters? And is this done with a MPPT algorithm? (MPPT is the maximum power point tracking). If yes, is it possible to keep constant Cp also with pitch control or active stall?

Comment: What does this mean: *tip-speed values of 8-10* and, what does this variant mean: *tip-speed ratio of 8-10*

Comment: What do you think pitch control does, since you mention it?

Comment: @Andyaka TSR for wind turbines is the ratio between the tangential speed of the tip of a blade and the actual speed of the wind..

Comment: @SolarMike the pitch control decreases Cp. Ahhhh, yes, it can only decrease (or theoretically increase) Cp, not keep it constant. Thank you. And about keeping constant Cp? How is it done?

Comment: Do you think frequency control might be more important? Since the whole point is to inject power into the grid...

Comment: @SolarMike I think not... But I remember that my electric power system professor mentioned converters when he talked about that. So this is why I mentioned them in my question. I want to thank you because you are trying to make me think about it, and I appreciate this a lot!

Comment: @SolarMike I know that for PV panels the MPPT is done by converters, in fact a converter is used also to control the rotational speed of a generator/motor

Comment: Once the max generator output has been reached and the wind speed continues to increase, what controls the blade speed?

Comment: @SolarMike I think a controller that switches the number of poles in order to keep constant the output power. Is it right? I reviewed the MPPT mechanism on internet and I find that for PV panels works with a DC/DC converter. In wind turbine since we have a generator I think it could work by switching the number of poles.

Comment: Have you worked on a wind turbine? Ever climbed a tower? Actually measured single or 3 phase voltages in one? The power factor? If the generator can’t keep the blades within their speed range, then the brakes are put on and the rotor rotated out of the wind to reduce the stress loading. Well worth finding out how small, medium and large ones work and their differences. Some manufacturers have done clever things, check out Vestas for example.

Comment: @SolarMike No, I'm a smart grid student. I have no practical experience. Thank you very much Mike for your help!!!

Comment: This is done in different ways for different turbines. What you learn from Hugh Piggott's homebuilds won't translate well to a 15MW Vestas turbine. Or vice versa. So, clarify what you're asking about.